# Shell restarts every time I import keras

Tags: python, keras

I just installed keras with pip and want to use it but I have some issues with it. It appears that the shell restarts every time I try to import it:

```
import random
print("1")
from keras import preprocessing
print("2")
```

Here's the output I get in IDLE:

```
1

============================================================================ RESTART: Shell ===========================================================================
>>>
```

I also tried to run the code from the terminal, here's the output:

```
*$ python3 main.py  
1  
Illegal instruction (core dumped)*
```

This seems to happend every time I import keras. Does anyone know a solution to this?
Python: 3.8.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few APIs of Keras are in still beta version for Python 3.8. 
So, make a virtual environment and downgrade to `Python 3.7`. 
And try again.